# runtime binding in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, drop-down-menu, binding

Hi I'm new developing Angular application. But, I want to bind a html select element option display in runtime take a look to my code. I'm using TypeScript.
I have this class.

```
export class Gender{
constructor(short:string, long:string){
    this.shortName = short;
    this.longName = long;
}
shortName:string;
longName:string;
```

}

That I'm trying to bind like this

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
        <option *ngFor="let opt of options" [ngValue]="opt">  
            {{opt."DYNAMICALLY INSERT THE NAME OF THE FIELD TO DISPLAY"}}
        </option>
    </select>
```

I want to define in runtime which field will be display. Let's say I want to do something like this

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
        <option *ngFor="let opt of options" [ngValue]="opt">  
            {{opt.WHICHFIELDTODISPLAY}}
        </option>
    </select>
```

so in the valriable WHICHFIELDTODISPLAY is the name of the field I want to display let say "longName".

So, how do I bind a dynamic value in a select option element using Angular 4 with TypeScript?

Comment: After of a few hours of researching and learning about Angular binding and learning more about TypeScript I found my solution.

 {{opt[WHICHFIELDTODISPLAY]}}

This works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try displaying the value placing within **`[]`** instead of **`dot operator`**

```
 <option *ngFor="let opt of options" [ngValue]="opt">  
            {{opt[WHICHFIELDTODISPLAY]}}
</option>
```